# Access Denied to S3 Objects Uploaded via SDK

Tags: amazon-s3

I am trying to create an IAM user that is permitted to:

- Upload Objects
- Get Objects
- List Bucket Objects

The policy seems to be working. However, I cannot view the images that were uploaded via the S3 SDK.  When referencing one of the image files in an HTML `<img />` tag, I get a `403 Forbidden` error. On the other hand, I am able to successfully view images that were uploaded via the AWS Console with the defaults, without setting any additional policies, etc.  Is there an attribute I'm not setting when uploading the image to S3 using the SDK?

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "IpAddress": {
                "aws:SourceIp": "MyIpV4Address"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:GetObjectAcl"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "IpAddress": {
                "aws:SourceIp": "MyIpV4Address"
            }
        }
    }
]}
```

The JavaScript code I am using to upload the files.

```
handleFileUpload(acceptedFiles, rejectedFiles) {
return Promise.map(acceptedFiles.map(file => {
    const object = {
      Key: `some-image-key.jpg`,
      Body: file,
      ContentType: file.type,
      StorageClass: 'STANDARD_IA'
    }
    return this.s3.putObject(object).promise(response => {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try uploading with an additional: `.withCannedAcl(BucketOwnerFullControl)`

> This specifies the owner of the bucket, but not necessarily the same as the owner of the object, is granted `Permission.FullControl`.

See:

- [withCannedAcl()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/PutObjectRequest.html#withCannedAcl-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CannedAccessControlList-)
- [CannedAccessControlList](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/CannedAccessControlList.html)